# CSS height property not working

Tags: html, css, height

I have been trying to solve this for days but can't solve it. (I'm usually quite okay with css). The website is www.auralaid.com.

On the homepage, there is a white spacing which I want removed. The class that is causing this issue is `flex-viewport` whose height is always slightly more than the "gray fabric image" it contains, leaving a white space at the bottom.

How do I remove the white space?

P.S. I can't set a fixed height otherwise the contained image will be cropped when minimising the browser.

[white spacing http://auralaid.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Screen-Shot-2013-11-09-at-9.34.02-pm.png](http://auralaid.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Screen-Shot-2013-11-09-at-9.34.02-pm.png)

Comment: Please post your code, so we can find the problem...

Comment: At a guess, try setting `display:block` on your images.

Comment: @Graham the images are already display:block

Comment: Then as Doorknob says, you'll need to post your code for anyone to get a better idea of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you should post your code to get the perfect answer but i guess there is a problem of positioning of the div in which these two images are and also set height of image according to the div positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should check your margins? We need the code to answer your question definitively.

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems the h1-tag is responsible as with

```
.slide-content h1 {
  display:none;
}
```

the white-space will disappear.